# Examples of SSH key exchange algorithms requiring encryption-capable host keys

Tags: encryption, ssh, digital-signature, key-exchange

In the [SSH spec, Section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7.1), key exchange algorithms are distinguished based on whether they require an "encryption-capable" or a "signature-capable" host key algorithm.

If I understood their details correctly, the well-known DH-based key exchanges algorithms such as `curve25519-sha256`, `diffie-hellman-group14-sha256` and `ecdh-sha2-nistp256` all require a signature-capable host key algorithm. What are examples of SSH key exchange algorithms that instead require an encryption-capable host key algorithm?